# How does join() work? (Multithreading in Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, join, methods, synchronized

I'm preparing for an exam and after going over some sample exercises (which have the correct answers included), I simply cannot make any sense out of them.

### The question

(Multiple Choice): What are the some of the possible outcomes for the program below?

A)
    Value is 1.
    Value is 1.
    Final value is 1.

B)
    Value is 1.
    Value is 1.
    Final value is 2.

C)
    Value is 1.
    Final value is 1.
    Value is 2.

D)
    Value is 1.
    Final value is 2.
    Value is 2.

### The Program

```
public class Thread2 extends Thread {

    static int value = 0;
    static Object mySyncObject = new Object();

    void increment() {

        int tmp = value + 1;
        value = tmp;

    }

    public void run() {

        synchronized(mySyncObject) {

            increment();
            System.out.print("Value is " + value);

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Thread t1 = new Thread2();
        Thread t2 = new Thread2();

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();

        System.out.print("Final value is " + value);

    }

}
```

The correct answers are: A), C) and D).

For case A) I don't understand how it's possible that both threads (after incrementing a seemingly static variable from within a synchronized block(!)) end up being set to 1 and the final value is thus 1 as well...?

Case C and D are equally confusing to me because I really don't understand how it's possible that main() finishes before both of the required threads (t1 and t2) do. I mean, their join() methods have been called from within the main function, so to my understanding the main function should be required to wait until both t1 and t2 are done with their run() method (and thus have their values printed)...??

It'd be awesome if someone could guide me through this.

Thanks in advance, much appreciated!
wasabi

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**There is something wrong with the answers or the question.**

Your understanding of `join()` is correct.  The "Final value is" message cannot be printed until both threads have completed.  The calls to `join()` ensures this.

Furthermore, the `increment()` method is only called from within a `synchronized` block keyed on a static field.  So there's no way this method could be called simultaneously by two threads.  The "Value is" output is also within the same synchronized block.  So there's no access to the `value` property from anywhere except within the synchronized block.  Therefore, these operations are thread-safe.

The only possible output from this program is "Value is 1. Value is 2. Final value is 2." (In reality, there are no periods or spaces between the outputs - I'm just matching the format of the answers.)

I cannot explain why this matches none of the answers except that whoever wrote the question messed something up.

Comment: Or that the answer is simply "none of the above". By the way, there will be no periods or spaces between the print statements (as in `Value is 1Value is 2Final value is 2`).

Comment: You know what they say.  Those who can, do.  Those who can't, teach.

Comment: Ya, the period thing I just didn't know how to format in another way here on stackoverflow for it to remain readable.

Comment: @rlibby +1 for having the eye of a grammar nazi or C compiler.

Comment: I've been trying to find the catch hidden somewhere in the question but I couldn't find any. I have to concede it is simply wrong.

Comment: Thanks all of you! You are all correct, indeed. I just got in touch with professor (this is one of the questions from an old final exam in my Computer Science course) and it turns out that the PDF contains an error. - Goddamn it! I wasted well over 5 hours on this... Nonetheless thank you very much.

Comment: I don't believe this answer is correct. I am posting my own answer.

Comment: I tried executing this program, and found every time output is "Value is 1. Value is 2. Final value is 2." how this is guaranteed, what i know is even static fields can be cached by threads and thus updates local cache and not guaranteed as when it update main copy. so update to variable value can be cached by threads and you may get "Value is 1. Value is 1. Final value is 2.". I am sure I am missing something?

Answer (score -2):

First i'd like to agree with rlibby. His answer can be proven by writing the program an present the output to the teacher.
If we omit that look at this:

its guaranteed to have two prints of 'Value is...'

it's not possible to print 'Value is 1' twice, since the increment is synchronized by a static object (this eliminates A and B)

the order of the print statements can not be forecasted

but: if we read a 'Final value is x' there must be a 'Value is X' too, no matter if before or after but it must exist

Comment: Who is rlibby? This is not a good answer.As others would be looking at this and asking the same thing, and it does sound like parrotting back some portions of the OP's question.